# Python: Getting a sudden HttpError 500: "Internal error encountered"

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api

This is my first project using API's so apologies if this is a silly question to ask!

I've written some code that has an input of a playlist url from Spotify. It then creates a new playlist on YouTube and adds the songs from the Spotify playlist into the YouTube one.

I had just got it to **work perfectly**. Then all I did was input a new Spotify url and it started giving me this error which I can't get rid of.

```
HttpError: <HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet%2Cstatus&alt=json returned "Internal error encountered.">
```

Could anyone tell me what the problem is? Thanks so much!

**EDIT: I went to the location of the error and this is the bit of code that is giving the error (I didn't write this bit, this is from HTTP requests)

```
def execute(self, http=None, num_retries=0):
        """Execute the request.

    Args:
      http: httplib2.Http, an http object to be used in place of the
            one the HttpRequest request object was constructed with.
      num_retries: Integer, number of times to retry with randomized
            exponential backoff. If all retries fail, the raised HttpError
            represents the last request. If zero (default), we attempt the
            request only once.

    Returns:
      A deserialized object model of the response body as determined
      by the postproc.

    Raises:
      googleapiclient.errors.HttpError if the response was not a 2xx.
      httplib2.HttpLib2Error if a transport error has occurred.
    """
        if http is None:
            http = self.http

        if self.resumable:
            body = None
            while body is None:
                _, body = self.next_chunk(http=http, num_retries=num_retries)
            return body

        # Non-resumable case.

        if "content-length" not in self.headers:
            self.headers["content-length"] = str(self.body_size)
        # If the request URI is too long then turn it into a POST request.
        # Assume that a GET request never contains a request body.
        if len(self.uri) > MAX_URI_LENGTH and self.method == "GET":
            self.method = "POST"
            self.headers["x-http-method-override"] = "GET"
            self.headers["content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            parsed = urlparse(self.uri)
            self.uri = urlunparse(
                (parsed.scheme, parsed.netloc, parsed.path, parsed.params, None, None)
            )
            self.body = parsed.query
            self.headers["content-length"] = str(len(self.body))

        # Handle retries for server-side errors.
        resp, content = _retry_request(
            http,
            num_retries,
            "request",
            self._sleep,
            self._rand,
            str(self.uri),
            method=str(self.method),
            body=self.body,
            headers=self.headers,
        )

        for callback in self.response_callbacks:
            callback(resp)
        if resp.status >= 300:
            raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
        return self.postproc(resp, content)
```

Comment: Hi. You need to share the relevant parts of your code, or it's not possible to debug.

Comment: @TomCarrick I think this is the relevant bit but I'm not 100% sure where the error is even coming from because it worked previously. Thanks!